# Logging Requests and Responses in Spring (including body) without Content-Type in Postman

Tags: java, logging

I am trying to log request with body using RequestBodyAdviceAdapter. It works fine if I set 'Content-Type = application/json' in the Postman. But there are many reason, I have to support requests without Content-Type in the query. I also tried to send the request without Content-Type and got the error:

> *Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported*

I read the post of Francisco Dorado to do the sample: https://frandorado.github.io/spring/2018/11/15/log-request-response-with-body-spring.html
.Please give me some advices to solve the problem!

Comment: Please help me!

Comment: Nobody can help me :(

Comment: Your controller method seems doesn't support text/plain on that resource and Postman is by default seems to be sending  text/plain from your request